# copyFromLocal: unexpected URISyntaxException

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to copy some files from my hard drive to HDFS , I am using this command

```
 hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Pictures/Event\ ordering/* input/
```

Is this the correct syntax ?

PS : I am using linux

PPS: I get this error

```
      copyFromLocal: unexpected URISyntaxException
```

Comment: It seems the whitespace, eventhough escaped, gets evaluated twice. Try escaping it twice, that is `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Pictures/Event\\\ ordering/* input/`.

Comment: @alvits I don't think it the problem that error occurred twice cause I have 2 field in that directory.

Comment: Do your filenames contain colon `:`? It is not supported at the moment https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7945

Comment: @alvits unfortunately yeah ! thanks a lot ! how can I mark you comment as an answer?

Comment: @alvits I spoke too early , I tried this on a file without ":"
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Pictures/openCV+Tank\ Detection/10.png input
still the same error.

Comment: Hadoop URI Syntax follows web URI syntax. Spaces must be represented as `%20`. Please try `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Pictures/Event%20ordering/* input/`. But this will cause the shell not to expand `*` into filenames and you'll get files not found. Try `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Pictures/openCV+Tank%20Detection/10.png input` and it should work.

Comment: @alvits hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Pictures/openCV+Tank%20Detection/10.png input worked , Any Idea how do I get to transfer all the files ? These guys just keep getting worse !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65118/discussion-between-riddle-and-alvits).

Comment: The easiest is to build the list of files then run copyFromLocal. Try this `for file in /home/hduser/Pictures/Event\ ordering/*; do files=${files},${file// /%20}; done; hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $(eval echo {${files#,}}) input`.

Comment: @alvits can i contact you via mail, i have one question regarding hadoop namenode?

Comment: @pulse - Sure. You'll find my email address in my profile.

Answer (score 28):

You need to represent *Space* as `%20`, i.e.

`Event ordering` -> `Event%20ordering`

try

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /my/local/dir/Event%20ordering/* input/
```

It will work.

Answer (score 3):

Remove space between Directory name and it will work

steps are as follows

1.Rename directory name and remove space between them

change **Event ordering**  to **Eventordering**

2 now run following command

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Pictures/Eventordering/* input/

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have files with space. Linux doesn't recognize spaces in their filenames. So, if you want to move those files, you first have to remove those spaces and then execute. Also, it is always recommended to not have space in Linux.

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Pictures/Eventordering/* input/
```